# Why my regular expression matches but does not capture a group?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the information from the following string:

```
//YES: We got a match.
```

I want to extract the information defining two groups

- Everything between `//` and `:`
- all the rest behind `:`

The pattern matches correctly but I cannot extract the groups.

```
String example = "//YES: We got a match.";
String COMMENT_PATTERN = "//(\\w+):(.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(COMMENT_PATTERN);

example.matches(COMMENT_PATTERN);            // true
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
matcher.group(1);                             // raises an exception
```

I tried it as well with named groups:

```
String COMMENT_PATTERN = "//(?<init>\\w+):(?<rest>.*)";
...
matcher.group("init");                        // raises an exception
```

Why my patterns cannot extract the specified groups?

Comment: First you need to put the `+` **in** the matching group, otherwise you'll get the last character matched in group 1 `(\\w+)`.

Comment: Mind to fix your syntax error in line 3? It's to short to be edited by somebody else ;)

Comment: What @HamZa meant was to remove the `+` after the group and put it inside.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call either `find()` or `matches()` on the `matcher` to cause it to run the matching process before you can extract groups. The

```
example.matches(COMMENT_PATTERN);
```

creates its own internal Matcher, calls `matches()` and then discards the Matcher - it's equivalent to

```
Pattern.compile(COMMENT_PATTERN).matcher(example).matches()
```